# Java - Object state does not change after method call

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Beginner java question, but I cannot understand how call-by-Value ( or Reference ) is working in the example below -

How come the String value is not modified after it exits the method while my custom String Object is. ? Same with other classes like Date..

```
public class StringMadness {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Native String";
    CustomStringObject cs = new CustomStringObject();
    System.out.println("Custom String Before: " + cs.str);
    hello(cs);
    System.out.println("Custom String After: " + cs.str);

    System.out.println("Native String Before: " + s);
    hello(s);
    System.out.println("Native String After: " + s);
}

private static void hello(String t) {
    t = "hello " + t;
}

private static void hello(CustomStringObject o) {
    o.str = "hello " + o.str;
  }
}

class CustomStringObject {

String str = "Custom String";
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Compare these two methods:

```
private static void hello(String t) {
    t = "hello " + t;
}

private static void hello(CustomStringObject o) {
    o.str = "hello " + o.str;
}
```

In the first case, you're assigning a new value to `t`. That will have no effect on the calling code - you're just changing the value of a parameter, and all arguments are passed by value in Java.

In the second case, you're assigning a new value to `o.str`. That's changing the value of a field *within the object* that the value of `o` refers to. The caller *will* see that change, because the caller still has a reference to that object.

In short: Java always uses pass by value, but you need to remember that for classes, the value of a variable (or indeed any other expression) is a reference, not an object. You don't need to use parameter passing to see this:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = foo1;
foo1.someField = "changed";
System.out.println(foo2.someField) // "changed"
```

The second line here copies the value of `foo1` into `foo2` - the two variables refer to the same object, so it doesn't matter which variable you use to access it.

Comment: Ahh.. I see it. thanks....  Originally, my `hello(CustomStringObject o )` was instantiating a new instance as in `o = new CustomStringObject()` and I noticed outside of hello method, the instanation never had any effect. This is what triggered the question.

Comment: @Jon Nice explanation. The Foo example helps. +1

Comment: If caller passes null reference then i have observed callee modification does not reflect to caller.why it is so ?

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming: For exactly the same reason as if you change the parameter itself, that isn't visible to the caller. The reference is passed by value...

Comment: How does this work with a 'primitive' object like Boolean? If I pass a method this object and then set it outside the method, does that setting outside the method now apply inside the method?

Comment: @BrianReinhold: All the wrapper types (`Boolean`, `Integer` etc) are immutable.

Comment: This -> "but you need to remember that for classes, the value of a variable is a reference" is what most other explanations tend to miss out on and is the basis of the MOST confusion on this point. But, @JonSkeet, you need to also mention it COPIES the reference and passes it, its not the orig ref.

Comment: @killjoy: You mean like after the example: "The second line here **copies the value of `foo1` into `foo2`**"? I don't think I'd ever talk about "the orig ref" any more than I'd talk about "the original integer".

Comment: @JonSkeet Guess I missed that...you're good then :)

Comment: to clarify even further, you can assign o to null then see the change is not visible ......private static void hello(CustomStringObject o) {
    o = null;
}

Answer (score 4):

There's an important difference between the two methods: using `hello(String)` you're trying to change the *reference* to the `String`, and with `hello(CustomObject)`, given a reference, you're using the reference to change a member of the object.

`hello(String)` takes a reference to a `String`. In the function you're trying to change which object that reference points to, but you're only changing the *pass-by-value copy* of the reference. So your changes aren't reflected outside the method.

`hello(CustomObject)` is given a copy of a reference to an object, which you can then use to change the actual object. Think of this as changing the *contents* of the object. So your changes *are* reflected in the caller.

Given a *reference* to an object, you can change the object using it's exposed methods/fields

Comment: Also, note that Strings are immutable. When you call hello(String) a copy of the string address is passed (e.g: 0xABC4). In that function when you assign a new value to a string this will generate a new address for that string (e.g: 0xABC5) that will not be seen outside your function.

Comment: @Adrian. Even if you use other mutable object like in this example CustomStringObject o if o is assigned a new value like o = new CustomStringObject() o.str = "New String", caller would still see the original str value of passed o object. As long as you dont change the reference of passed object, changes reflect to the caller

Answer (score 0):

`t` will point to new object and scoped to method only, so changes not visible outside.

Second case, the value you are changing will be updated to object,so those changes are visible after method call.

Comment: It's not really because strings are immutable. Even if this were a StringBuilder, assigning a new value to the parameter wouldn't affect the caller...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Agree. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because for the String you are just changing the local parameter reference.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work because String is an immutable object